# Compare blank string and null spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing an SQL query that joins two tables. The problem that I am facing is that the column on which I am joining is `blank (""," ")` on one table and `null` on the other.

Table A

| id | col |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 | SG |

Table B

| id | col |
| --- | --- |
| a | null |
| b | null |
| c | SG |

```
source_alleg = spark.sql("""
    SELECT A.*,B.COL as COLB FROM TABLEA A LEFT JOIN TABLEB B 
    ON A.COL = B.COL
    """)
```

For my use case blank values and null are same. I want to do something like `Trim(a.col)` which will convert blank values to `null` and hence find all the matches in the join.
Output:

| id | col | colb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | either null or blank | either null or blank |
| 2 | either null or blank | either null or blank |
| 3 | SG | SG |

Answer (score 1):

In sql the NULL are ignored during a join unless you use a `outer join` or `full join`
more information : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-left-right-and-full-outer-join/

if you want to convert the nulls to a string you can just use an `if`

```
select 
   if(isnull(trim(col1)),"yourstring", col1),
   if(isnull(trim(col2)),"yourstring", col2)
      from T;
```

Comment: I want to compare the null values with the blank values in the ON statement.

Comment: The data is huge so I want to avoid any updates to the table.

Comment: @VanditGoel in that case you should be able to do it in the `ON`, for instance `ON  if(isnull(trim(T1.col)),"yourstring", T1.col) = if(isnull(trim(T2.col)),"yourstring", T2.col)`